# Where to find older sets (eg. Classic Space)?

Tags: sets, shopping, space

Can people share their experiences on how they locate older sets? Have you had luck with flea markets, garage sales, thrift stores, etc.? Or is everything done through eBay and BrickLink? Any comments appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Brick Answers. Unfortunately, I don't think we can answer your question as it stands: it isn't really a question with a specific answer, so it isn't a great fit for this site. Moreover, I'm not sure how other people's answers to this question could help you find what you're looking for? That said, if you can rephrase / expand on your question so that it is a better fit for the site, we'll do what we can to help.

Comment: BTW: http://www.classic-space.com/forum/ may be a useful resource.

Comment: I guess I am looking for ideas on where to look for sets. And it does not have to be Classic Space - I just used that as an example.

Comment: The problem is that the things sold at garage sales or whatever varies from place to place and from month to month. Even the types of outlet varies considerably by geography. New Zealanders tend to prefer Trade Me over eBay, for example. Your best bet is probably to ask around locally, or use the big international sites like BrickLink.

Comment: And yes, we're LEGO Answers. I knew that really... ;-)

Comment: I may go against the current here, but I think the question has merits - a lot of people seek to buy older sets, to complete collections or out of pure nostalgia; and I for one feel it would be nice to have a good compilation of means to achieve that.  Yes, the question is broad, but iconic enough that it shouldn't be a problem. The question and existing comments already show good elements of answer.

Comment: And, @KenCenerelli, welcome to Bricks.se no matter how the question turns out! :-)

Comment: @Joubarc: Interesting point. Let's go meta! http://meta.bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/257/shopping-questions

Comment: Thanks everyone for taking the time to view this thread. I hope it can spur some discussion. Also thanks to Joubrac for the welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the places you can buy old (discontinued) sets include:

**Online**

- [BrickLink](http://www.bricklink.com/)
- eBay
- TradeMe
- Amazon marketplace
- Generic on-line toy stores that carry old stock
- Some LEGO discussion forums have areas for buying and selling

**Locally**

- Toy shops and LEGO stores sometimes carry old stock
- Stands at exhibitions and shows
- Garage sales
- Thrift stores
- Charity shops
- Flea markets
- Car boot sales
- Jumble sales
- Through newspaper ads
- Lego User Groups
- Other AFOLs

**Other Alternatives**

- Buy the parts separately and assemble the set from them